# How to make proper module translations in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8, translation-scheme

I have to prepare modules translations, but the documentation is not helping me.

I know i can use *.pot files, but i can't fully understand how dupal is managing translations.

If i add translations/example.pot drupal will take care of everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First modify module_name.info.yml add:

```
'interface translation project': block_example
'interface translation server pattern': modules/examples/%project/translations/%language.po*
```

Then create in your module directory folder *translations*.

Add translations/language.po files, where you will store translations.

language.po:

```
msgid "your id to translate"
msgstr "translations test"
```

template.html.twig:

```
<p>{% trans %}your id to translate{% endtrans %}</p>
```

Then go to your Drupal admin page Configuration/User interface translation, there you can filtr your msgid and see already translated files.

You may have to use IMPORT {just upload .po file}
Translations are imported automatically when you install your module.